# Best practice to convert data.responseText to jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any difference between this code

```
$.get('http://www.google.com/', function(data) {
    var html = $('<div></div>').html(data.responseText).children();
});
```

and this code

```
$.get('http://www.google.com/', function(data) {
    var html = $(data.responseText);
});
```

What should I use and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the simpler 2nd option does what you want, why would you not use it?  Please offer some reason why anyone should spend time on this question.

Comment: i think option 1 is more flexible for changes or extends